# SQL Oracle issue with PROCEDURE

Tags: sql, database, oracle, procedure

I have some issue with procedure and i can not find solutions. Some error with end loop.

Have you got some idea to resolve it?

Please find the attached file with screenshot of error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PR_GEN_TRANSAKCJI
IS
KL NUMBER;
ZN NUMBER;
L_POZ NUMBER;
POK NUMBER;
CE NUMBER;
CZP NUMBER;
DNI NUMBER;
POZ NUMBER;


BEGIN

KL :=FN_LOSUJ_KLIENTA();
SELECT ZNIZKA
INTO ZN
FROM KLIENT
WHERE ID_KLIENTA=KL;

INSERT INTO FAKTURA (ID_FAKTURY, DATA_WYSTAWIENIA_FAKTURY, WARTOSC_FAKTURY, 
WARTOSC_FAKTURY_PO_ZNIZCE, ID_KLIENTA, WARTOSC_ZNIZKI) VALUES
(SEQUENCE_FAKTURA.NEXTAL, SYSDATE, 0, 0, KL, ZN);

 LICZNIK :=0;
L_POZ :=FN_LOSUJ_POKOJ();
SELECT CENA_ZA_DOBE
INTO CE
FROM TYP_POKOJU, POKOJ
WHERE POK=POKUJ.NR_POKOJU AND POKOJ.ID_TYPU_POKOJU = 
TYP_POKOJU.ID_TYPU_POKOJU;
DNI :=FN+LOSUJ(1,5);
CZP :=DNI*CE;
POZ :=LICZNIK + 1;

INSERT INTO FAKTURA_DETALE (POZYCJA, CENA_ZA_POKOJ, ID_FAKTURY, NR_POKOJU, 
LICZBA_DNI) VALUES (POZ, CZP, SEQUENCE_FAKTURA.CURRVAL, POK, DNI);
LICZNIK := LICZNIK = 1;
EXIT WHEN LICZNIK > L_POZ;
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Thank you for your help!

[image]

Comment: I see no corresponding `LOOP` for `END LOOP`. What's that  `END LOOP` supposed to end?

Comment: okay i see but when i add the loop before the function this procedure does not understand LOOP.

Comment: That's what you get when you write ugly code. If you properly formatted it, indented, you'd see that END LOOP doesn't have its pair - *beginning* of the loop. You said that you added LOOP keyword but got another error. Well, it is you who knows what this code should do, which part of it should be executed in a loop. The rest of us doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have tried `SHOW ERRORS` to debug your output as its the most convenient feature nevermind 
you have missed `LOOP` start statement fix this as there's only `END LOOP` visible in your code

Idk where do you want to start the loop. A guess that you are exiting on some value which relates the other values manipulated at the start of begin itself so can try putting `BEGIN LOOP ..... END LOOP`

Comment: I did it, the i have more errors with my code, I guess that i need prepare new procedure :P